# Simulation in R for multistage sampling

Tags: r, loops, simulation, sampling

I am trying to simulate a multi stage sampling scheme as following:

1. I have N = 90 (Population) size
2. I need to choose 20 sample out of N = 90 (without replacement) with equal probability
3. Then I need choose 17 sample out 20 (so in this case my previous sample become population i.e. N=20) without replacement and with equal probability
4. Then I need to find 3(20-17) samples and choose 2 sample out of 3 (Here N = 3) without replacement and with equal probability.

I need to replicate whole for 1000 times and calculate mean for step 2, step 3, and step 4

''' replicate(1000,sample(1:90,20,replace = F, prob = NULL)) '''

I am trying to using this but I am not getting results.

Comment: What are you getting? An error? If so, share the exact error message.  Note that `Null` isn't a reserved word in R, in R it's `NULL` (all uppercase). Plus you also seem to be missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @MrFlick I am getting a matrix of 1000x20 but I am not able to proceed with next parts where I need to choose 17 samples from 20 and thereafter.

Comment: If you use `sample()`, the results are returned in a random order. If you need 17 out of the 20, just use the first 17. Then use the next 2. As long as you resample every time, that would be fine. You don't really to do any extra sampling for the other parts.

Comment: I need random 17 in order to validate the theory. Its like N = 90 then choose n1 = 20 from 90, then I need to choose n2 = 17 from 20(earlier selected) then I need to find those 3 sample which weren't chosen and take 2 from these 3

Comment: If you are only using that set of 20 once, then it's totally fine to just use the first 17 like I mentioned. There's no added benefit to shuffling again. They are already random. If you wanted to repeatedly choose 17 from the same subset of 20, then that would be different, but that's not what you've described. If you need help with the concepts of statistical sampling, then maybe you should first seek help at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic.

Comment: Each time sample will shuffled when I choose 20 out of 90 therefore set of 20 will be changing every time (for every iteration). I am struggling with code. I am clear with sampling scheme and logics. If you can share piece of code so I can try

Comment: set.seed(885); N = list(); n1 = list(); n2 = list(); n3 = list();                                                                                                                                   
  for (i in 1:100){
  N[[i]]<- rnorm(90,20,5)
  n1[[i]]<-sample(N[[i]],20,replace = F)
  n2[[i]]<-sample(n1[[i]],17,replace = F)
  n3[[i]]<-sample(n1[[i]] [!n1[[i]] %in% n2[[i]]],2,replace = F)
}